# How to find 'utm_content' of a campaign?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm a new user of Google analytics. I wanted to keep tracks of clicks on banners on a webpage.

There are three banners, so I generated this url:

- http://mysite.com?utm_source=clientsite&utm_campaign=sitelaunch&utm_medium=banner&utm_content=footer
- http://mysite.com?utm_source=clientsite&utm_campaign=sitelaunch&utm_medium=banner&utm_content=header
- http://mysite.com?utm_source=clientsite&utm_campaign=sitelaunch&utm_medium=banner&utm_content=sidebar

The keys used:

- Utmsource: clientsite. A mnemonic name for the referral site
- utm_campagin: sitelaunch. The name of my campaign
- utm_medium: banner. Since they are banners
- utm_content: depends on the position of the
  banner.

I've run this campaign for a couple of days and now I have some results on my dashboard.

My question is: how can I actually check my campaign in Google Analytics, down to the clicks on the different banners?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about Google Analytics, which is more appropriate for [webmasters.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to see it is in  Acquisitions > All Traffic > Source / Medium. As all your mediums are the same, you will need to add a secondary dimension and choose Advertising > Ad Content which will display the utm_content tag.